# Get request to return entries with multiple search criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write a Get request in Node.js to search the MongoDB database with the project name field and one other field. the project name field criteria should always be there but the other field can change(description, date etc.).

So far I've got this code which only includes the project name and I'm struggling to figure out how to also add the filter for another field.

My code so far:

```
app.route('/api/issues/:project')

    .get(function(req, res) {
      let project = req.params.project;
      let filterObject = Object.assign(req.query);
      filterObject['project'] = project;
      console.log(filterObject);
      IssueModel.find(filterObject, (error, finddata) => {
        if(!error && finddata){
          return res.json(finddata);
        }
      })
      })
```

Thanks in advance for the help!